# How to get a value from anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ss8gzdao/):

```
var test = function(){
    return{
        value: "hi",
        func1: function(){
            func2();
        }()
    };
}();

function func2(){
    alert(test.value);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong? I can't get test.value.

Comment: you haven't passed test into your second function func2() uses a different scope, so you need to pass the variable into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `func2()` is called from the [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572) for the `func1` property in the IIFE that constructs the object to be assigned to `test`. Before it assigns to `test`. And it tries to access the `test.value` property, on a variable that is yet `undefined`, and throws a `ReferenceError` therefore. (See also [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572))

I think you are looking for

```
var test = function(){
    return{
        value: "hi",
        func1: function(){
            func2();
        } // <-- no invocation here, make `func1` a method not `undefined`
    };
}();

function func2(){
    alert(test.value);
}

test.func1(); // "hi"
```

([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ss8gzdao/2/))

Comment: super, and I searched some information about IIFE. I gained a lot, thx!

Comment: I should've linked it…

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code you'll be getting an `undefined`. Why? Well because you haven't given enough time for your `test` to actually **initiate itself** ( and the fact that what you're doing this in a synchronous way).

Try this *asynchronous* solution.

```
var test = function(){
    return{
        value: "hi",
        func1: function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ func2(); }, 50);
          //you can also just do
          //setTimeout(func2, 50);
        }()
    };
}();

function func2(){
    alert(test.value);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xe0d0rqf/)

Also notice that you don't return anything to your func1 since it auto invoques itself. Later on if you try to do `test.func1()` it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign an object literal to `test`. However, to build that object, you call `func2`. That function attempts to access `test`, but at that point it still is undefined.

Therefore, you should call `func2` after assigning the object to `test`:

```
var test = function(){
    return {
        value: "hi",
    };
}();
test.func1 = function(){
    func2();
}();
function func2(){
    alert(test.value);
}
```

However, note that's a bit weird, because the anonymous function doesn't return any value. `func2(); test.func1 = undefined` would be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi mentioned you want to use [Imidiatelly Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) but your syntax is wrong.

see [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ss8gzdao/4/)

```
var test = (function(){
    return{
        value: "hi",
        func1: function(){
            func2();
        }
    };
})();

function func2(){
    alert(test.value);
}
```

With ( at the start of your function and at the end of it before you actually immediately call it